# char column converted to varchar still inserting padding

Tags: sql, char, padding, varchar

I don't really know how to explain this one. I've taken a table, created a copy of it with a specific column as varchar instead of char. Then I've copied the data from one table into the new one. However, when I then programmatically add a new value to the table, the column that was previously char(200) is still being padded with space up to the 200 characters. I've tried doing a cast on the insert, a convert, and even RTrim(CAST([MynCharColumn] As nVarChar)) as found on another question on here, but no matter what I do the value keeps being padded as if it were still a char.

Comment: How are you inserting it programmatically? Are you possibly adding the padding yourself?

Comment: Can you post the code and table schema?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Have you checked for hidden characters? Some characters might not be visible when looking at the string, but would remain unaffected by RTRIM, especially if you're using NVARCHAR.

Comment: The RTRIM actually does its job and trims the previous column entries as they are put into the new table. It's then going forward any new entries are automatically being padded.

I'm inserting them by taking the value of a textbox on a webpage (ASP.NET with VB.NET). In the same insert function I'm taking another textbox value and inserting it into another varchar column in the same table and it does not receive any padding. That code is the same and that's why I'm leaning towards the table/column being the cause.

It is either MS SQL 2005 or 2008. The column with the issue is Description. The

Comment: The column with the issue is Description. The one that works using the same code is Name. In fact any other of the nvarchar columns do not have the issue. Only when items are inserted into Description are they padded to 200.


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPart](
 [PartID] [int] IDENTITY(60001,1) NOT NULL,
 [PartType] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [PurchasePrice] [float] NULL,
 [UnitCost] [float] NULL,
 [CurInventory] [int] NULL,
 [Manuf] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [State] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [Status] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [Description] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
)

Comment: Just mocked this up on my local SQL Server 2008 and inserting with RTRIM works as expected for me - whitespace is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess: if you are using some form of ORM the ORM code might still have the column as char(200) and insert it as char. Or, if you are using a stored procedure, did you change the datatype there?

Comment: That was exactly it. My stored procedure (which someone else had written) was still passing the value as char(200). I updated that and the padding was not inserted on new values. Thanks!